# Graphing tool that supports two Y-Axis?

Tags: android, graph

The graph I am trying to create is a line graph with six separate functions, all of which need to be easily shown and hidden from the graph and the legend. It also needs to use dual Y-axis'. The reason for the dual axis is that 3 of the functions have a very small range of Y-values, and the other 3 functions have a very large range of Y-values.

I tried to replicate an example in excel:

[image]
Above shows how my graph is currently set up. The values of the `pink` line range from [-300,300], while the values of the `blue` line range from [-50,50].

I would like the graph to be drawn like it is shown below:
[image]

I am currently using the [`GraphView library`](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html), but cannot find any support for dual Y-axis.

Comment: why would you choose such an unpedagogical way of visualize your data?

Comment: I don't know what that means, I googled it and the synonyms are un-educational? It wasn't my choice to have the graphs like this, the users involved have been using a graph built like this for many years on a different platform, and my employer requested it.

Comment: @vidstige Just wondering, if you think this is a bad way to visualize what else would you suggest? If I try to separate this into two separate graphs it becomes very hard to see it clearly since the graphs are made half the size.

Comment: perhaps out of topic, but it completely depends on what you want to visualize. Probably you want to make it easy to relate the two graphs. In that case one way is to have them over/under each other, that way the time will align up. You can still have different scales on the y-axis like in your example above so that the diagrams appears in equal height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AChartEngine is a good charting Library.  http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

I am pretty sure it can do this.

Comment: I was gonna answer the same. AChartEngine for the win. I used before and it is VERY configurable.